# Proper way to use function properties in React components

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and from the limited tutorials etc. that I've done I've seen that the application state lives at a level that may be different than the component that's rendering it, for the component to be able to edit the state a function is passed in as a property and used that way. This is all fine but at what point is it ridiculous to be passing a function into a nested component? For example, I have

```
<App>
  <Container>
    <Item>
      <ItemChangeMenu/>
    </Item>
  </Container>
</App>
```

`App` has the state and the function `changeItem`, should the `Container`, `Item`, and `ItemChangeMenu` all have an `onItemChanged` property that passes it along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main approaches to pass `props` down to the children:

1. Explicit - passing the props as individuals on each level:

   ```js
       const Container = (props) => (
         <Item
           onItemChange={props.onItemChange}
           value={props.value} />
       );

       const Item = (props) => (
         <ItemChangeMenu
           onItemChange={props.onItemChange}
           value={props.value} />
       );

       const ItemChangeMenu = (props) => (
         <input
           onChange={props.onItemChange}
           value={props.value} />
       );

       class App extends React.Component {
         state = { value: 'Hello World...' }
         onItemChange = ({ target }) => {
           this.setState(state => ({ value: target.value }))
         }
         render() {
           const { value } = this.state;
           return (
             <Container
               onItemChange={this.onItemChange}
               value={value} />
           );
         }
       }

       ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <div id="root"></div>
   ```
2. Implicit - passing the entire `props` object but spreading it (new
   [ES2018 feature](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html)):

   ```js
       const Container = (props) => <Item {...props} />;

       const Item = (props) => <ItemChangeMenu {...props} />;

       const ItemChangeMenu = (props) => (
         <input
           onChange={props.onItemChange}
           value={props.value} />
       );

       class App extends React.Component {
         state = { value: 'Hello World...' }
         onItemChange = ({ target }) => {
           this.setState(state => ({ value: target.value }))
         }
         render() {
           const { value } = this.state;
           return (
             <Container
               onItemChange={this.onItemChange}
               value={value} />
           );
         }
       }

       ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <div id="root"></div>
   ```

There are pros and cons for each pattern of course.

**With the explicit pattern**, you get a clear view of which props are being passed down, and you can manually decide what props you want to pass.

The main caveat with this approach though, it is tedious and quite hard to refactor.

**With the implicit pattern**, you just pass an object and forget about it, you need to pass a new prop? it will already go down the chimney. If you ever need to refactor, change names of props or re-order the components hierarchy, then no need to change the props names.

However, the main caveat with this approach, is that you will probably pass more props then you need to. this can lead to unnecessary calls for `componentWillReceiveProps`.
Of course you can use destructure to minimize it:

```
const {someProp, someOtherProp, ...rest} = this.props;
// ...  
<Child {...rest} />
```

But this is almost the same thing as taking the explicit approach.

**There is a 3rd option** though it is not related to the `props` API.
It called [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).  With the context API you can "skip" levels and grab `objects` directly from the grand parents.

Sounds great, but if you will look at the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context):

> Why Not To Use Context
>
> The vast majority of applications do not need
>   to use context.
>
> If you want your application to be stable, don’t use context. It is an
>   experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of
>   React.

As said in the docs, this is an *"experimental API and it is likely to break"* and that day has come, [a new context API](https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/new-version-of-context/text/0000-new-version-of-context.md) is on it's way and will might change the way we work with `props` or react all together.

The `context` feature is not something that no one use by the way, important libraries like `react-redux`, `react-router`, `react-mobx` are using and dependent on it.

Comment: So from the sounds of it using the explicit pattern and passing the function along a couple of levels deep to a child component is not uncommon. Thanks.